# fatal error while using Zxing for coding QR code reader app

Tags: android, xml, zxing

I have used the below code to create QR code reader with Zxing predefined, but i am getting fatal exception. Also i have defined the core.java with in my project libs folder. Could someone please help me to solve this issue?

**MainActivity**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;   
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
private Button scanBtn;
private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    formatTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
    contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_content);

    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this); 

}

public void OnActivityResultListener(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        //we have a result
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + contents);
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + format);
        }
     else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         // Handle cancel
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Scan was Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
         toast.show();
    }
   }

  }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE,PRODUCT_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
/*  if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_button){
        //scan
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();

        }     */

}
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.qrcodereader.MainActivity" >

<Button android:id="@+id/scan_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="scan" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scan_format"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scan_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scan_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**QRcodeReader Mainfest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.qrcodereader"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
           android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="landscape"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Error log**

```
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.qrcodereader
/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: android.view.InflateException:
Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line 
#35: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView
(PhoneWindow.java:207)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate
(CaptureActivity.java:140)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 11 more
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 23 more
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:218)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 26 more
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 30 more
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010010 a=-1}
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:292)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>
(FrameLayout.java:88)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>
(FrameLayout.java:84)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at 
android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.<init>
(ActionBarView.java:1258)
01-03 13:42:20.931: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 33 more
```

Comment: Have you added jar file to your libs folder?

Comment: Yes i have added and i have added it in preference also

Comment: I don't know exactly where you are getting error. your code seems ok though check this link http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=3324

Comment: Is there any specification like depend upon version?

Comment: Yes may be it will. What is 35 line number in your xml file?

Comment: android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

Comment: I think problem is because of that just remove that line for test.

Comment: Also i am getting error in the Zxing with i imported, getting Migrate Android code

Comment: Oh that means you didn't imported properly. you need to copy that library project to your workspace too??

Comment: Ok So i have to copy that project into my workspace and import that will that work?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing  the following in your manifest file

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Check this link
https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded#older-sdk-versions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).